# Recursive powershell directory object losing directory level

Tags: powershell, recursion

When I execute the following code, assuming X:\ is a multi-level directory tree, it begins to throw strange errors on the second pass.

For example, let's assume X:\ has the following structure

```
X:\
--1stLevelDir
----2ndLevelDir
--Another1stLevelDir
```

---

```
function recurse{
    param([System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $folder)
    foreach ($dir in GCI $folder -Directory) {
        Write-Output $dir.FullName
        recurse $dir
    }
}

recurse (get-item 'X:\')
```

That code produces the following output

```
X:\1stLevelDir
X:\1stLevelDir\2ndLevelDir
GCI : Cannot find path 'X:\2ndLevelDir' because it does not exist.
At foreach line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
recurse $dir.FullName
```

[IO.DirectoryInfo] objects expand to the short name, which is treated as a relative path - and looked for in the folder you are in.

Edit: or

```
function recurse{
    param([System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $folder)
    foreach ($dir in GCI $folder.FullName -Directory) {
        Write-Output $dir.FullName
        recurse $dir
    }
}

recurse (get-item 'X:\')
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, this looses my FileSystemInfo type but I can work without it. Out of curiosity is there a convenient way to maintain that type without making a get-item call?

Comment: @Preston yes, put the `.FullName` in the `gci` call instead of in the recurse call.